# How to do a redirect when @PreAuthorize returns false

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am learning `Spring MVC` and `Spring Security`.

How can I return a redirect for a `@PostAuthorize` annotated `@Controller` when the annotation expression returns `false`?

```
@PostAuthorize("hasRole('page')")
```

If the line above returns `true` there is no problem.

If the line above returns `false` the page still renders, but all variables are empty, Ex: shows a simple table with head and without any row.

So: How to return a redirect when `@PostAuthorize` returns `false`?

Answer (score 1):

Handle AccessDeniedException exception in controller advice

```
@ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
public void handleAccessDeniedException(AccessDeniedException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    //redirect 
}
```